# Register app in gitlab and use the same client_id and secret in another app

Tags: git, github, oauth-2.0, gitlab

I have been trying to see if this use case is even valid. I have 2 separate domains (abc.example1.com) and (abc.example2.com). Now I have abc.example1.com is already registered in my gitlab server and working fine. I have another requirement where I am thinking to use the same client_id and Client_secret as I got in the previous registration . My logic simply is to obtain the access to server auth and callback.

I am unsure how OAuth would receive this and is there any logic that gives me allow/suspend in case I use same client_id and secret for these separate domains so I don't need new registration every time in gitlab.

Appreciate any help or insight , I also don't know if there is anyway to test this locally?

More info: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this myself , since each app registration is being treated a new authentication and new token is being generated , you need to re-create the IDs. Oath won't allow different domain to use same IDs.